# BeautifulSoup Python3 append multiple links output to single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    links = ["https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.0",
             "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.40",
             "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.80"]


    def get_span():
        for url in links:
            page = requests.get(url) 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser") 
            t1 = str(soup.findAll("span", id=re.compile('^msg_')))
            print(t1)
            t2 = [x for x in re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', t1)]  
            t2.sort(key=float, reverse=True)  

            t3 = "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic"
            for hn in t2:
                if len(hn) >= 9:
                    hn = '{}={}'.format(t3, hn)
                    print(hn)


    get_span()
```

> Hello! 
>   My code iterates items in `link`, then finds the span with
>   `id=msg_`, then finds all numbers in `id=msg_`, sorts them in 
>   descending order. Problem is that it iterates first item and gives output
>   of it, then second item and so on, so out put contains 3 lists. So it
>   sorts items separately.. I want to get a output with all 3 items from `links`
>   sorted in one list.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: sorted ```links=``` by span in one list
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254720.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254480.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254448.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5252504.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5235729.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add items to list and then sort the final list before returning it.

For example:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


links = ["https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.0",
         "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.40",
         "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.80"]

def get_span(links):
    rv = []
    r = re.compile(r'\d{7,}\.\d+')
    for url in links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        rv.extend(a['href'] for a in soup.select('span[id^="msg_"] > a') if r.search(a['href']))
    return sorted(rv, key=lambda k: float(r.search(k).group(0)), reverse=True)


all_links = get_span(links)

# print links on screen:
for link in all_links:
    print(link)
```

Prints:

```
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255494.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255416.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255389.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255376.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255316.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254720.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254480.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254448.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254287.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5252504.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5251621.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5250998.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5250388.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5250185.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5248406.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5247112.0

... and so on.
```

---

EDIT: If you want to show link text n

```
ext to url, you can use this example:

import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


links = ["https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.0",
         "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.40",
         "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.80"]

def get_span(links):
    rv = []
    r = re.compile(r'\d{7,}\.\d+')
    for url in links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        rv.extend((a['href'], a.text) for a in soup.select('span[id^="msg_"] > a') if r.search(a['href']))
    return sorted(rv, key=lambda k: float(r.search(k[0]).group(0)), reverse=True)


all_links = get_span(links)

# print links on screen:
for link, text in all_links:
    print('{} {}'.format(link, text))
```

Prints:

```
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255494.0 NUL Token - A new hyper-deflationary experiment! Airdrop!
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255416.0 KEEP NETWORK - A privacy layer for Ethereum
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255389.0 [ANN] ICO - OBLICHAIN | Blockchain technology at the service of creative genius
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255376.0 UniChain - The 4th Generation Blockchain Made For The Smart Society 5.0
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5255316.0 INFINITE RICKS ! First Multiverse Cryptocurrency ! PoS 307%
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254720.0 [GMC] GameCredits - Unofficial & Unmoderated for Censored Posts.
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254480.0 [ANN] [BTCV] Bitcoin VaultA higher standard in security
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5254448.0 [ANN] Silvering (SLVG) token - New Silver Asset Backed Cryptocurrency

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working as i wanted. Maybe you know how to sort with text next to post?  for example. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3920469.0 [ANN][ICO]HoweyCoins: '
 'the only BitcoinTalk-endorsed ICO - GUARANTEED PROFIT